# How to find density of a wire when we know information of it in polar form

Tags: homework-and-exercises, integration, density

We know that the wire has the "path" in the shape of the polar graph
$$r = \theta, \quad 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2 $$
and we know at point $(\theta,\theta)$ the density of the wire is $2\theta$.

I know that the equation for density is the integral:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} f(r \cos(\theta),r \sin(\theta)) \sqrt{r^2 +1}d\theta = \int_0^{\pi/2} f(\theta \cos(\theta),\theta \sin(\theta))\sqrt{\theta^2 +1}d\theta \, .$$

From the information given I'm pretty sure I only know that $f(\theta,\theta)=2\theta$ but not what $f(\theta \cos(\theta),\theta \sin(\theta)$ equals.

Can anyone help me with this question?

Comment: If we assume that $f(x,y) =2\sqrt {x^2+y^2}$, then $f(\theta \cos {\theta},\theta \sin {\theta})=2\theta $

Comment: but isn't that at the point $(\theta cos(\theta), \theta sin(\theta) )$ not point $(\theta, \theta)$ or am I way over complicating this?

Comment: Then use $f(x,y)=x+y$

Comment: This seems a better fit for [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/). However, the best advice here is to rederive everything from scratch so that you understand where it is coming from. Then the issue with $f$ will disappear. (Btw your upper integration limit is currently inconsisistent with $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$).

Comment: If you are given with only $f(\theta,\theta)$ then the problem is maybe the given function is in the form of $f(r,\theta)$ instead of $f(x,y)$. Are you sure the function is in the form of $f(x,y)$

Comment: Reign, I have no idea how to derive the equation for a line integral in polar form without starting from cartesian and converting

Also I originally posted this question on math.se but got 0 responses sooo... no this seems like a better spot.

Comment: @MathsRrough Is this the original question or you worked on it and shared us in that form ? Is there a way that you can share us the original question if thats the case ?

Comment: @MathsRrough What is the f(x,y) here in any case ? Also in 2D line integral actually contains 2 integral but then we convort them into 1 using the given conditions.

Comment: @Reign The first two lines are all that was given, in their exact form. The rest was me trying to figure it out unsuccessfully.

Comment: All that was given was "wire has the path in the shape of the polar graph $r=\theta$ and that the density of the wire at $(\theta,\theta)=2\theta$. The question was to find mass.

Comment: @MathsRrough Do you know the answer ? I am thinking some stuff but I cannot be sure.